# Dynamic Link doesn't work on iOS but works perfectly on Android

Tags: flutter, firebase

I configured the dynamic links for my app but it works perfectly on Android but it only directs me to the appstore not the actual app. Here are the configurations.

**flutter doctor -v**

```bash
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale en-KR)
    • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at /Users/hyungilkang/fvm/versions/3.7.3
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/2.18.7/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/hyungilkang/fvm/versions/3.7.3. Consider adding /Users/hyungilkang/fvm/versions/3.7.3/bin to the front of your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9944297138 (13 days ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
    • Engine revision 248290d6d5
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/hyungilkang/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.38+21-CA (build 17.0.5+8-LTS)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone (mobile) • 00008110-001E2D4A220A401E • ios          • iOS 16.1.1 20B101
    • macOS (desktop) • macos                     • darwin-arm64 • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
....
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                android:host="incle.page.link" 
                android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                android:host="incle.page.link" 
                android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
....
```

**iOS Configurations**

**Info.plist**

```xml
...
    <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://incle.page.link/share</string>
    </array>
...
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Bundle ID</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.incle.incleClientApp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
...
```

**Runner.entitlements**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applink:incle.page.link</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**The way I create my dynamic links**

```dart
    Future<void> onClickShare(String storeID) async {
    final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
        link: Uri.parse(
            "https://incle.page.link/share?route=${StoreDetailScreen.routeName}&argument=$storeID"),
        uriPrefix: "https://incle.page.link",
        androidParameters:
            const AndroidParameters(packageName: "com.incle.incle_client_app"),
        iosParameters:
            const IOSParameters(bundleId: "com.incle.incleClientApp"),
        socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
            description: storeInfoState.value!.data!.storeDescription,
            imageUrl: Uri.parse(storeInfoState.value!.data!.storeImage.isEmpty
                ? ''
                : storeInfoState.value!.data!.storeImage.first),
            title: storeInfoState.value!.data!.storeName));
    final dynamicLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(
        dynamicLinkParams,
        shortLinkType: ShortDynamicLinkType.short);

    Share.share(dynamicLink.shortUrl.toString());
  }
```

I believe I elaborate all the configurations that is needed to make Firebase Dynamic Links work on Flutter. It works like magic on Android.

But on iOS, when I click 'Open Link' button in the preview page, it just redirects me to the App Store. I don't know if it's the problem if I tested it with the app running with debugger but at least it didn't work with Testflight-installed app.

Please help me and save my day gurus! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was an extremely simple problem.

`applink:incle.page.link` should've been fixed into `applinks:incle.page.link`

Hope no one would make same mistake and suffer for days like I did!

Comment: where and how to add this applink:incle.page.link should've been fixed into applinks:incle.page.link ? can you put detailed solution?

Comment: @FaizFareed as you can see in the question, it's in Runner.entitlements file which is located in <your_project_root>/ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements